# PHP first result is missing

Tags: php, database

Hi I am retrieving results from a database once a link is clicked however the first record isn't displaying but all the others do. I don't know why. If I change the SQL to DESC then my first result shows but the last then doesn't.

Am I doing something wrong/has anyone else had a similar issue?

```
<?php
    require_once("../db/db_connection.php");
    $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE campname=? ORDER BY order_ref ASC");

    $sql->bind_param("s",$_GET["campname"]);            
    $sql->execute();
    $result = $sql->get_result();
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {        
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    }
    $db->close();
?>

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {        
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        ?>  
        <?php echo $row["title"]; ?>
        <?php
                }
            }

        ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `fetch_assoc()` before you get into the loop to display the data, remove the following lines...

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {        
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
}
$db->close();
```

So your code should look something like...

```
$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE campname=? ORDER BY order_ref ASC");

$sql->bind_param("s",$_GET["campname"]);            
$sql->execute();
$result = $sql->get_result();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {        
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        ?>  
        <?php echo $row["title"]; ?>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: It done the trick and works as it should do now. Thanks a lot Nigel.